# Cannot cast 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser`1[System.Int32]]'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

**PROBLEM:**

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser`1[System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DAL.User]'.'

**RELEVANT CODE:**

```
...
public class SocialNetworkDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser<int>, IdentityRole<int>, int> 
...
public IQueryable<User> FindAll()
        {
            var allUsers = (IQueryable<User>)_socialNetworkDbContext.Users;
            if (allUsers == null)
            {
                throw new NoRecordFoundException();
            }
            return allUsers;
```

**TRIED:**

1. `public class SocialNetworkDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>, IdentityRole<int>, int>`

//no exception but this code breaks

```
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, model.Role);
```

2. public IQueryable FindAll()
   {
   var allUsers = (IQueryable)_socialNetworkDbContext.Users.AsQueryable();
   if (allUsers == null)
   {
   throw new NoRecordFoundException();
   }
   return allUsers;

//the same exception

3)

```
public IQueryable<User> FindAll()
        {
            var allUsers = (IQueryable<User>)(IEnumerable<User>)_socialNetworkDbContext.Users;
            if (allUsers == null)
            {
                throw new NoRecordFoundException();
            }
            return allUsers;
```

// the same exception (unable to cast to IEnumerable). Cast to ICollection (unable to cast to ICollection)

Would be very thankful for any advice!!!

Comment: You are trying to cast `IdentityUser<int>` to `User`. What is that User type?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You're trying to return an `IdentityUser` in a method that returns a `DAL.User`. You can't just cast between two unrelated types. You'll always get the same exception, telling you that you can't cast an `IdentityUser` to a `DAL.User`. Either change the return type or map one type to the other.

Comment: @juunas  public class User : IdentityUser<int>

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos shall I do mapping of User inherits from IdentityUser<int> as i put in my previous comment?

Answer (score 2):

You should change your DbContext to use the actual user type:

```cs
public class SocialNetworkDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, IdentityRole<int>, int>
{
}
```

If you have a class for the roles, you should use that as the generic type argument as well.
This way you won't need any type casts.

Comment: I tried in this way, but then the following code does not work:                                                
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? What error do you get?

Comment: when i send request via PostMan this line (var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password); ) is read and in the result not executed. The following error is shown: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Discriminator', table 'SocialNetwork.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.   If IdentityDbContext has <IdentityUser<int>...> then no such issue

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it seems that the `_socialNetworkDbContext.Users` was stored the IdentityUser, instead of User model, right? So, after query data from the Users table, you could use the following code to convert the query result:

```
    public IQueryable<User> FindAll()
    { 
        var allUsers = _socialNetworkDbContext.Users.Select(c => new User()
        {
            UserName = c.UserName,
            Email = c.Email,
            //... other properties
        }).AsQueryable();
        if (allUsers == null)
        {
            throw new NoRecordFoundException();
        }
        return allUsers;
    }
```

**Update**

You can refer the following sample code:

Add an ApplicationUser class to customize the Identity User model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{ 
    public string CustomTag { get; set; }
}
```

Use the ApplicationUser type as a generic argument for the context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>, int>
{
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Update Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml and replace IdentityUser with ApplicationUser:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using WebApp1.Areas.Identity.Data
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Update the `Startup.ConfigureServices` and replace `IdentityUser` with `ApplicationUser`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{ 
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Then, enable migration and generate the database.

After creating new user, the AspNetUser table data as below:

[image]

Create a UserViewModel and add the required properties:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the Controller, use the following code to query the user table:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = FindAll();
        return View();
    }
    public IQueryable<UserViewModel> FindAll()
    {
        var allUsers = _context.Users.Select(c => new UserViewModel()
        {
            UserId = c.Id,
            UserName = c.UserName,
            Tag = c.CustomTag
        });
        //if (allUsers == null)
        //{
        //    throw new NoRecordFoundException();
        //}
        return allUsers;
    }
```

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: thanks, I tried but some properties I have in user, do not exist in IdentityUser<int> thus I have CS1061 error (no definition)

Comment: Hi @Svit_O, please check the update, based on your code, I create a sample, it works well on my side, you can refer it.

Answer (score 0):

> try First(); or FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

change your code :

```
    public async Task<List<User>> GetAllUsers()
        {
            var allUsers =  await _socialNetworkDbContext.Users.ToListAsync();
            if (allUsers == null)
            {
                throw new NoRecordFoundException();
            }
            return allUsers;
         }
```

Comment: The code complains about `User` and `IdentityUser`, not `List`. This code causes far more problems though by loading everything in memory